# Auto List out properties of a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Say you have a class:

```
class Bob
{
    public int Something { get;set; }
    public int Something2 { get; set; }
    public int Something3 { get; set; }
}
```

when you go to create a new instance of Bob:

```
Bob bob = new Bob {
    Something = 1,
    // Is there a way to automatically write out all properties rather than having to know what they were to type them out?
}
```

Is there a way to automatically write out all properties rather than having to know what they were to type them out? so Visual Studio 2013 might end up doing this for you so you know what to fill out:

```
   Bob bob = new Bob {
        Something = ,
        Something2 = ,
        Something3 =
    }
```

Comment: Whoever just edited the post deleted my damn edit.. can you put it back please? IT IS A VISUAL STUDIO QUESTION. NOT A c# ONE PLEASE

Comment: @OndrejJanacek In this case, it seems to be *only* about the IDE...

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thanks Vache for the fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either Visual Studios own Intellisense or R# will suggest the properties if you press Ctrl-Space or whatever your shortcut to Intellisense is. The feature is intelligent enough to only suggest those you did not already assign. That way you can fill them one after another until the intellisense does not pop up any more.

Comment: Perfect.. THANKS A BUNCH! Oh this helps me out massively across loads of things now. nice! why did I not know this? Oh don't answer that...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio should have autocomplete when you use variable initialasition that way.

when you place the comma, hit enter and it will list the remaining properties.

If you use CTRL + SPACE it will give a list of ALL properties